# Rails: where to put and how to call scheduled clean-up methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I've written a couple of clean-up methods for a Rails app and I'm trying to figure out where the best place to store them is:

```
def flush
  @documents = Document.ready_to_flush
  @documents.each do |document|
    document.update_attributes(generated: false,
                               high_res: nil,
                               low_res: nil)
    server_url = "#{App::Application.config.server}/tasks/documents/#{document.id}/flush?token=#{App::Application.config.server_token}"
    response = HTTParty.get(server_url)
    if response.ok? && task_id.present?
      render json: "Assets PDFs for #{document.id}."
    else
      render json: "Assets for #{document.id} not flushed."
    end
  end
end

def clear_temporary_directory
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob("#{::Rails.root}/public/temporary/*"))
end
```

I'm calling them from `schedule.rb` (with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem) like so:

```
every 1.day, at: '12:17 am' do
  runner 'clear_temporary_directory', environment: 'production'
end

every 1.day, at: '12:20 am' do
  runner 'flush', environment: 'production'
end
```

Just not really sure where the best place to store those top methods would be. Are there best practices for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really. If you're going to make more of these, you may want to make an `app/something...` folder but otherwise, `app/helpers/` should work fine (Don't forget to include it.)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid using helpers. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If this is the right answer, could you mark as correct and upvote?

Comment: I will provided no one else has any insight.